# hasMany with additional information

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'd like to get the following working:

I got a `UserGroup` that should have `discounts` on a list of `ProductGroups`.

### Example:

`UserGroup`

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Test",
        "discounts": null,
    }
}
```

`ProductGroups`

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Group1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Group2"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Expected result

`UserGroup`

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Test",
    "discounts": [
      {
        "productgroup_id": 1,
        "discount": 0
      },
      {
        "productgroup_id": 2,
        "discount": 10
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So now I'd like to know: How to save this the best? First I thought about JSON. The problem: If the `ProductGroup` is being deleted, the `UserGroup`-`discounts`-JSON is not updated using a cascade.

Comment: How about you make eloquent relations and store the discount in a pivot table. Then using the `withPivot` function you can include the correct discount. il try write this in an answer. is `discount` a model ?

Comment: That's a good idea. At the moment discount is not a model, but it's possible to change this.

Comment: It doens't have t be a model

Comment: @SPQRInc have you looked at `one-to-many-polymorphic-relations`, it seems like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a pivot table `user_group_product_groups` with the columns `user_group_id`, `product_groups_id` and `discount`

In your `ProductGroup` model add

```php
public function userGroups(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserGroup::class)->withPivot('discount');
}
```

In your `UserGroup` model add

```php
public function productGroups(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(ProductGroup::class)->withPivot('discount');
}
```

You can now use `$productGroup->userGroups` and it wil include the discount from the pivot table.

Or use `$userGroup->productGroups` and it wil include the discount from the pivot table.

Comment: Alright, I will try that. At the moment I'm getting ` Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.user_group'` (should be `user_groups`) in tinker after extending `Pivot`, but I'll check that out.

Comment: I have just added basic class references in the relations as i have no idea about your namespaces. You might what to check those

Comment: It seems correct, so I deleted mine and up-voting this.

Comment: Seems like hasMany in `UserGroup` does not work:

```
        return $this->hasMany(ProductGroup::class)->withPivot('discount');
```

Leads to 

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany::withPivot()'```

Comment: Ahh sorry i believe both should be `belongsToMany` i updated my answer. As is described in the [many to many docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)